# Autocompletebox tags functionality like gmail

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using telerik controls in an MVVM pattern. I'm currently using my autocompletebox for my emailing functionality. It is used as my "To Recipients". At the moment it works great for 1 to 1. Select a person from the autocompletebox drop down and they are selected as a token. I'm trying to enhance this so that the autocompletebox itemsource will have tags added. And if a Tag is selected, it'll populate anyone that belongs to that tag.

For example

Bob and Steven have the tag developer

If I then select "developer" from autocompletebox drop down, bob and steven should then populate "To Recipients".

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" 
                            WatermarkContent="Search ..." 
                            Style="{StaticResource MultiAutoBox}" 
                            SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedUsers, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                            cal:Message.Attach=
                           "[Event KeyDown] = [UpdateParticipants($source, $eventArgs)];
                            [Event SelectionChanged] = [CheckTags($source, $eventArgs)]"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Name" Grid.Row="1"
                            TextSearchPath="Name"/>
```

I can populate the itemssource with the tags and I have the SelectionChanged that calls CheckTags. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
public void CheckTags(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Logic for [How to determine what was added/removed here]


    If item added is tag, loop through itemsource and find and add people with that tag and change selecteditems to match

}
```

Comment: Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I'm using Caliburn, which is INotifyPropertyChanged which is a more enhanced verison